# Automatic Changing of values in excel

Tags: vba

[Data after closig and opening of excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyi14.jpg)I am having a tricky situation with my excel. I have written a VBA code which collects HEX data from many CSV file and converts it into decimal and stores it into decimal. This works perfectly when tested I had no problem, I had also saved it. But when I reopen the excel half the cells are back to Hex format and only half are in decimal. I don't know why this happens. When doing it for first time it works but on saving closing it and again opening it gives me this problem 
Here is the vba code 
[OriginalData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w4lf.jpg)

```
Sub Sample()

Dim myfiles
Dim i As Integer
Dim J As Long
Dim l As Long
Dim LastRow As Long


myfiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", MultiSelect:=True)

If Not IsEmpty(myfiles) Then
For i = LBound(myfiles) To UBound(myfiles)
     With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & myfiles(i), Destination:=Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
        .Name = "Sample"
        .FieldNames = False
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 3
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
Next i

    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For J = 2 To LR

    Cells(J, 4).Value = CLng("&H" & Mid(Cells(J, 4).Value, 4, Len(Cells(J, 4).Value)))
    Cells(J, 5).Value = CLng("&H" & Mid(Cells(J, 5).Value, 8, Len(Cells(J, 5).Value)))
    Cells(J, 6).Value = CLng("&H" & Mid(Cells(J, 6).Value, 8, Len(Cells(J, 6).Value)))
    Cells(J, 7).Value = CLng("&H" & Mid(Cells(J, 7).Value, 8, Len(Cells(J, 7).Value)))
    Cells(J, 8).Value = CLng("&H" & Mid(Cells(J, 8).Value, 4, Len(Cells(J, 8).Value)))
    Cells(J, 9).Value = CLng("&H" & Mid(Cells(J, 9).Value, 8, Len(Cells(J, 9).Value)))

   Next
   LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   For l = 2 To LastRow

   'Cells(l, 14).Value = Left(Cells(l, 3).Value, 3)
   'Cells(l, 13).Value = Right(Range(l, 3).Value, 4)
   '(l, 12).Value = Val(Left(Right(Cells(l, 3).Value, 7), 2))
   Cells(l, 10).Value = Left(Cells(l, 3).Value, 3) + Val(Left(Right(Cells(l, 3).Value, 7), 2)) / 60 + Right(Cells(l, 3).Value, 4) / 3600

   Next

   Else
   MsgBox "No File Selected"
   End If

   End Sub
```

I parse more than  one CSV files at the same time so when on reopening only the parse of the first file remains in decimal format others change to original hex format

Comment: Can we see screenshots of the original data, then the data that is/isn't working? That might help.

Comment: Hi @David I have attached the screednshots by editing the question

Comment: The screenshot is top as "Data after opening and closing of excel" and "Original Data"